Adding images to a PDF generated by an API and Node.js
I would like to display an image on a PDF that is generated from HTML code (I am using two libraries, Mustache and html-pdf-node), but when I send a POST request with Postman, the image does not appear :(
Here is a complete screenshot
I've done this (https://i.sstatic.net/JpCEyR52.png)

There are 2 meanings to add an image to PDF:

Using a src attribute on an <img> tag - then you need use absolute, web accessible, URL and it will work.
By embedding the image file itself into the document - then it will work even offline.

If you post your code as text it would be easier to make an example.

Hi there,
I don't really understand your answer because I've already used absolute links like this: file:///emplacement/of/image.png, and it doesn't work either.
All the code is in the image that I sent via this link: https://i.sstatic.net/JpCEyR52.png.
There's too much code to send you via Stack Overflow.

Oh and I think the problem is more because of the html-pdf-node API.
